# Does pickaday call HAVE to be at bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pikaday

I'm trying to get the Pickaday script working in a DNN module.  I'm not getting any errors in the console, but the script isn't firing when I click on my inputs.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_StartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date" ></asp:Label><br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_StartDate" CssClass="datepicker">    </asp:TextBox>

<br /><br />
<asp:Label ID="lbl_EndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date" ></asp:Label><br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_EndDate" CssClass="datepicker">    </asp:TextBox>

<script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pikaday.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pikaday.jquery.js"></script>

<script>
     $('.datepicker').pikaday({ format: 'MM/DD/YYYY' });
</script>
```

I noticed that the script indicates to "Add the JavaScript to the end of your document.".  Since this is a DNN module - I can't really do that.  Will this script simply not work unless the script call is the final thing before the closing body tag?

Comment: Have you tried waiting until the DOM is ready by wrapping your JS in `$(function(){ ... });`?

Comment: Also, be sure to include the jQuery library before attempting to invoke `$()`  or `jQuery()`.

Comment: jQuery is included by DNN.  Forgot to mention that.  I can tell that the pickaday code is firing as I put a random break point in both the pikaday.js and  pikaday.jquery.js scripts.  The line is hit.  But the calendar pop-up is not showing.  Not getting errors that my CSS is not loaded.  Still trying to figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

No, the code that initializes your objects on the page should be called when all scripts are loaded, and jquery gives you an easy place to do this, nl in the [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, like:

```
$(function() {
   // insert your code to be run at the start here
});
```

or via

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // insert your code here
});
```